# When to use present perfect and when present perfect continuous?

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, progressive-aspect

In my English book it says ''I have done'' is used when an action is ended, but where there are consequences in the future. For example: 'There has been an accident, and as a result the street is blocked'.

I understand how to use it, but I am puzzled about the difference with the present perfect continuous' For example: 'It has been raining (and now the street is wet)'. Why could we not use the present perfect?

Why can't we say ''It has rained''? When should we use the present perfect and when the present perfect continuous?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/112007/12918

Answer (score 1):

It is very much like the difference between the present and the present continuous.

PRESENT.
'I run on Thursdays', 'I run at the St Botolph's Sports Club'. 'I am running as I speak'.

'It rains often in Manchester.' 'It is raining right now.'

PERFECT.
'I have run in all the races.' 'I have been running all afternoon.'

'It has rained every day for a week.'  'I notice from the wet street that it has been raining.'

I am not conversant with the rules as I did not learn English from a book but at my mother's knee. But perhaps some of the above examples will help you understand.